# SQLAlchemy model definition at execution

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

I'm writing an ORM using Elixir and SQLAlchemy to handle moving spreadsheet-like data into SQL. In general, the content of the spreadsheet-like data is unknown, and pyparsing parses (meta) data about the spreadsheet-like data from a text file

(example: the census publishes the Current Population Survey in fixed with flat files, accompanied by a txt file which describes contents of the data, including column specification and documentation for each column in data)

As I've imagined it, the ORM looks something like this

```
class DataSet(entity)
    """a collection of many spreadsheet-like files"""
class DataFile(entity)
    """describes a single spreadsheet-like file"""
class Variable(entity)
    """describes a single column in spreadsheet-like file"""
```

So, this model describes the contents of a bunch of flat files sitting on a hard drive. Now, if I want to take those flat files to SQL, should I

1. try to write the SQL as a string and substitute information from the model written above
2. try to define a new Elixir/SQLAlchemy entity
3. some third option

At the end of the day, what *I think* I want is all of the spreadsheet like data files in SQL as spreadsheet-like tables, and Elixir/SQLAlchemy magic for handling all the meta data

I've read a lot of SQLAlchemy docs and what not, but they all seem to be written for 'so you want to write a blog' type applications, or at least applications where the structure of the data is completely identified before writing code.  I guess I'm trying to write a model which is agnostic about its column specifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought would be that elixir won't benefit you much towards a solution.

My advice would be to go with 2) in that you try to build up a table based on the metadata that you have.
(re)read the schema docs to see how you'd add columns programmatically and then create the table:

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/schema.html

e.g.

```
sqla_metadata = sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData()

type_mapping = {'int': Integer, 'text': String} # etc.
cols = []
for (col_name, col_type) in your_parsed_metadata.fields:
    cols.append(Column(col_name, type_mapping[col_type]))

cols.append(Column('datafile_id', Integer, ForeignKey("datafile.datafile_id"), nullable=False),)
new_table = Table(your_parsed_metadata.tablename, sqla_metadata, *cols)
sqla_metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Then you can start inserting into your newly created table.
You'll also want to keep track of the mapping between generated tables datafiles.
You could reuse a generated table for another datafile if it's schema matched.